# ChartJS - Error when clicking on the last bar of the chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm creating a dashboard page for my company and I'm using chart js to do this, but I'm having a weird problem using ChartJs.

I have a specific widget that loads a bar chart. In this chart, I have a breakdown functionality, in other words, when I click on a bar another chart with more detailed information should load. This is happening normally, however when I click specifically on the last bar of the chart (last index and last datasetindex), I get an error that crashes my application.

The error appears to be related to the second level chart, something like if the information for the chart has not yet been loaded. (but again, only happens when I clicked the last bar from the first level chart).

Attached is the error I receive, and it appears to be a compilation error, as I have to reload the page to be able to use the application again.

Has anyone faced something like this?

[image]

I'm using react-chartjs2 and ChartJS, and I'm rendering the chart using this function:

currentLevel is a react state that contains the current drilldown level of the widget, so it will render the widget based on that.

```
const handleFirstLevelClick = async (event, chartElement) => {
  try {
    await firstLevel(chartElement);
    let selectedApplication = getFirstLevelDatasets()[chartElement[0].datasetIndex].label;
    let selectedMonth = getFirstLevelLabels()[chartElement[0].index];

    if (widget[1].arrayList.filter((item) => item.job_number.includes(selectedApplication.substring(selectedApplication.lastIndexOf("#")+1)) && item.month === selectedMonth).length >0) {
      setCurrentLevel(2);
    } else {
      setCurrentLevel(1);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

const handleSecondLevelClick = async (event, chartElement) => {
  try {
    await secondLevel(chartElement);
    let selectedJob = getSecondLevelLabels()[chartElement[0].index];
    // if selectedJob ()
    if (widget[2].arrayList.filter((item) => item.job_number.includes(selectedJob.substring(selectedJob.lastIndexOf("#")+1))).length >0) {
      setCurrentLevel(3);
    } else {
      setCurrentLevel(2);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

const firstLevel = async (chartElement) => {
  const { datasetIndex } = chartElement[0];
  let selectedApplication = getFirstLevelDatasets()[datasetIndex].label;
  let selectedMonth = getFirstLevelLabels()[chartElement[0].index];
  setSelectedApplication(selectedApplication);
  setSelectedMonth(selectedMonth);
}

const secondLevel = async (chartElement) => {
  const { index } = chartElement[0];
  let selectedJob = getSecondLevelLabels()[index];
  setSelectedJob(selectedJob);
}

const renderComponent = () => {
  switch (currentLevel) {
    case 1: 
      return <Bar data={dataFirstLevel} options={firstLevelChartOptions} />
    case 2:
      return <Bar data={dataSecondLevel} options={secondLevelChartOptions} />
    case 3:
      return <MailingStatusTable data={dataThirdLevel} />
  }
}

dataSecondLevel = {
  labels: getSecondLevelLabels(),
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Delivered Percent', 
      data: getSecondLevelDeliveredPercent(),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
    ...*the same for other datasets*
}

const secondLevelChartOptions = {
  onClick: handleSecondLevelClick,
  ...*all other options here*
}
```

As you can see there is a couple functions that retrieves the chart values. This functions are being called as soon as the chart renders.

The handleSecondlevelClick function is incrementing the currentLevel state and after incrementing it will perform a new render with the new chart or table according to the currentLevel.

Comment: Please provide the handleSecondLevelClick function

Comment: Text should not be presented as images. Please see [ask].

Comment: Maybe a typo? You're declaring it as `const handelSecondLevelClick` but later use `onClick: handleSecondLevelClick.`

Comment: Sorry, I just mistyped in the post. The code is correct.